# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts RDS with mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Estoy tratando de hacer una conexión remota desde mi API web en net core 3.1 y cuando hago un scaffold, devuelve el siguiente mensaje donde no se puede conectar.

Ya he probado varias alternativas para abrir los puertos de mi RDS sin éxito, ¿qué me puede faltar?

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 442
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line 112
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line 141
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 645
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 312
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 280
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Scaffolding.Internal.MySqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection connection, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Scaffolding.Internal.MySqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```